# How to make few locations use the same svn revision in jenkins

Tags: svn, hudson, jenkins

I have a jenkins project with few svn locations. How can I make them all checkout the same revision when using scm integration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I understand your question you could use the @Revision-syntax.

**Syntax:**
`<SVNURL>@Revision`

**Example 1:**
`svn://server/projectA/trunk/@1234`

The above example would checkout the `trunk` of `projectA` at revision 1234.