# how to use env variables from properties file in jenkins

Tags: continuous-integration, hudson, environment, jenkins

I want that my jenkins job will use env variables from a properties file. is that possible, and how?
Thanks, Ohad.

***EDIT:*** I want environment variables to be resolved when checkout from svn, so that few projects will have the same revision. I am trying to use a solution suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6755157/how-to-make-few-locations-use-the-same-svn-revision-in-jenkins).

Comment: it might be late for this but on windows you can access env variables with %VariableName% on linux I think it works with $VariableName

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of plugins used for this type of thing. You might want to take a look at the following two. I have feeling the one your looking for is the second one.

1. [Setenv](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Setenv+Plugin)
2. [Envfile](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Envfile+Plugin)

If you want to get all manual about it you can also do this.

Manage Jenkins -> Configure System -> Global Options -> Environment variables

Goodluck!

Comment: The second solution is similar to what I need, the only problem is I need to use the env variable on the svn checkout/update as a revision. and from the tests I did this step doesn't resolve environment variables.

Comment: umm? why dont you specify the revision on the checkout?

Comment: I added an explanation in the question.